# How tall or short is Link when compared to the average human?

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda

Since it's the 30th anniversary of *The Legend of Zelda*, I've been wondering about a few Zelda-related things.

Link has pointed elf-like ears, so at first I thoughs he was short (as most elves are portrayed as short). Although he was raised among them, he's not [Kokiri](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Kokiri) but rather he is [Hylian](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Hylian), so he eventually grew to be much taller than Kokiri. [Ganondorf](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Ganondorf) is [gerudo](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Gerudo) and is much taller than Link.

I don't know if there are regular humans in the *Zelda* series, but if there were/are, how tall would they be compared to Link?

[image: An image comparing heights of "The Legend of Zelda" characters. Ganondorf is tallest, followed by Zant, followed by Human Form Midna, followed by Shad, followed by Princess Zelda, then Link (just a wee bit shorter than her highness), then Ilia, then finally the very short Imp Midna.]

Comment: It's important to note that, despite us referring to him as an adult, Link has not shown up as an actual, fully grown adult in any games yet. He is always a teenager.

Comment: Which version of Link?

Comment: @RogueJedi Normal Link, so I guess [teenage Link](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/zelda/images/8/80/Link_Defending_(Soulcalibur_II).png/revision/latest?cb=20090726014102), _not_ the [child Link](http://zeldawiki.org/images/thumb/5/53/Young_Link.png/110px-Young_Link.png) or the [stupid toon Link](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/ssbb/images/c/cd/Toon_Link_Phantom_Hourglass.png/revision/latest?cb=20120827125123&path-prefix=es)

Comment: Where are their arms?! That image! Sheesh.

Comment: @Lexible - I think they’re t-posing, so their arms are pointing straight out towards the “camera” from their shoulders.

Comment: @RedCaio Huh... that makes sense... I thought is was like dismemberment chic or something.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Average height.

In Ocarina of Time 3D - When you visit the Lakeside Laboratory there is a pool. The pool has what is presumably a meter measuring stick running the depth of the pool.

[image]

[Supposedly](http://zeldawiki.org/Link#Trivia) if Link stands up against it, his height is measured at 1.7 meters or 66.92 inches (or approximately 5'7"). I haven't managed to find a video yet where he stands right next to in. In this screenshot he is standing close, but not against it, and he appears to be 1.5 meters. Google claims the average height for an adult human on earth is 5.6', which is 1.70668m. **This puts Link almost exactly at the average height of a human today ([worldwide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_height#Average_height_around_the_world)).**

[image]

*Screenshots taken from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUvq_OFkzg8) video.*

### Update

There was some discussion in the comments of what the unit of measurement was in the game. I always assumed it was meters.

Well thanks to [Clockwork](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120214/how-tall-or-short-is-link-when-compared-to-the-average-human/120244?noredirect=1#comment553532_120244) we can now see the unit of measurement is indeed meters (as stated by the characters in the game).

[image: You may not have noticed, but I've been watching you. You dove 2 meters just now. But I wouldn't call that a real dive.]

Comment: But that would make him *below average* for a male, no?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I am willing to allow for a certain margin of error to account for the .00668 meter discrepancy.

Comment: Google claims the average male height is 5'10''. That's got to be at least one standard deviation below average if he's 5'6'' - 5'7''.

Comment: @AdrianLarson https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=average%20human%20height  it says 5.6ft.

Comment: Depends on your [search term](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=average+male+height). [This chart](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://halls.md/chart/MenHeightWhite2.gif&imgrefurl=http://halls.md/average-height-men-height-weight/&h=456&w=864&tbnid=ckIcMg9Ccq4SnM:&tbnh=97&tbnw=184&docid=RWFp0dK8Vduq1M&usg=__wS_IBmCzdo4QAg1hd00iAh_YfhY=&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD05Sv6IvLAhVDRCYKHS8oCWoQ9QEIIDAA) implies 1.7m is below the 25th percentile.

Comment: @AdrianLarson If you look at the page that chart belongs to, it says "The national average height of men in America."  I could certainly believe the average height across the whole Earth would be lower, especially since China and India have averages below 170cm.

Comment: Link's a teenager in OoT, and TP, and SS. He has never been shown in adult form, so he still has time to grow!

Comment: @Axelrod he could 19 and still technically a teenager and yet have reached full adult height.

Comment: We know he's 16. 8 years of growth to come!

Comment: I've never played the game, but what makes you think that scale is a meter high?

Comment: @DougWarren I'm making an assumption because it is a Japanese game.

Comment: That's not a meter stick. How do you know what unit of measurement that is? I think the fact that Link is 4' 2" makes more sense.

Comment: @Bloxxer How do you know it isn't a meter stick? Where are you getting 4' 2"?

Comment: The unit of measurement for length could be anything relevant to Hylians in Hyrule.

Comment: I know this is very old, but I just booted my old game on N64 to check this out. The pool stick has 10 bold red bars: the first one starts on water level, and the last one is on the ground below water. When you jump into the water (without diving), Link's legs reach the 3rd bar, and the guy says you went down 2 meters. However, the highest I could reach by diving was 7 meters (if I go lower, he simply says Link is the best diver), so I can't tell if it's truly 9 deep. Otherwise, here's a screenshot of Link standing right beside the stick: https://www.aht.li/3324593/oot_pool_meter_stick.JPG

Comment: Just adding the screenshot of the guy saying the 2 meters (to confirm the units are metters): https://www.aht.li/3324595/oot_not_a_real_dive.JPG ; However, I tried again, and it looked like: his head reached below the 2nd bar, his body the 3rd and his legs the 4th. So I don't know how the guy is measuring the deepness.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, so I may be wrong in my observations, and as there is no way for me to get Link to stand directly against the wall, I will put a range for the height instead of an exact answer.

[image]

As you can see here, Link is standing next to the meter right after he stretched and is almost standing straight up. It's a bit slanted, so Link's head is probably just under the mark, rather than right on it. His distance from the meter also means he is still a bit too tall, however, the meter is also a bit incorrect with its bottom mark being slightly above the ground, putting Link a bit higher on the scale. Link's shoulder width is also wider than his hips, so his distance may not actually be as great as it seems. His head is slightly slanted, his neck is forward, and his knees are slightly bent, so more height can be added in, but not a lot. Taking all of this into account, he's probably at 1.69 m (5'6.48") or 1.7 m (~5'6.9") in this picture.

I actually took a lot more pictures, but I can't upload all of them, since they ended up being too large. In one of them, I got link to stand beside the meter, and he stood at just over the 1.6 m mark; it looked to be at 1.61 m (5'3.36") or 1.62 m (5'3.7"). In fact, all of the times I took picture of him standing beside the meter (without him stretching), he stood at around 1.6 m (5'3").

If you are wondering why these are in meters, the scientist in the lab tells you how many meters you go down whenever you dive into the water. This is because he was watching you, according to his dialogue. With the ruler being in the water and the dialogue only giving the dive lengths in meters, we are led to assume the lines are meant to be in meters.

Personally, from my own observations, I'd say Link is somewhere between 5'3" and 5'6.9". I'd like to believe he's 5'4.5" or 5'5", if not 5'6", but I can't be sure. If I could get clarification from a developer of the game, I'd be more confident in my words, but I can't actually do that. Who knows? I could have measured wrong. Maybe Link is actually under 1.6 m. In any case, if you want better information, you could try playing the game and looking at it yourself. It is really easy to do this if you wear the Zora's Tunic since you'd be able to stay underwater.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, Link is definitely 5'3 to 5'0 in most games, ocarina of time is no joke though, 17 years old, in Oot, link is 5'3, but in Tp, the hero's shade tends to be 5'8, or 5'11 or even taller which means oot link did grow in his years. Tp link is shorter than almost everyone, even the princess. Zelda in tp looks to be 5'4 or 5'3, making link one inch shorter than her, so he's either 5'2 or 5'3, but tp link is depicted as a man in his 20's instead of a teen. But it's just strange that in Botw he has a short, feminine stature that no other Npc has, Every Npc is taller than him, the only Npc's he is taller than is the children, some of the old people, mipha and maybe Zelda(their heights always change in the camera angles, even when they're side by side.) which means he's probably the height of 4'11-5'3, but i'm not good at calculations. This means that Link is not the average height of a human male, but of a human female. (OUCH!)

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Where are you getting these figures from?

Answer (score -3):

I think it is canon, I am not sure but in Hyrule historia (if I remember right) so is Link 5'3 or about 153.5 cm, It may have been in the japanese scans or in the english translation. But as I said I am not sure... Zelda is clearly taller than Link in 99% of the games, as well as all adults/young adults almost tower over Link.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Can you try and track down a quote so you can add evidence into your answer?